# WS-Federation claims authentication (MVC.Net)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, saml, claims-based-identity, ws-federation

I need sample code for claims authentication for WS-Federation in MVC.Net apps. (Not .Net Core) Is there any blog/article or Microsoft documentation on how to do this? Both how to configure the app and code samples.

-Must use System.IdentityModel
-SAML is the user principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [old blog entry of mine](https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/11/simplest-saml11-federated-authentication.html) should be all you need. It shows how to implement WS-Fed with System.IdentityModel and two modules, the SAM and FAM.

If you don't trust the FAM module or you can't use it for any reason, the [next blog entry](https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2018/09/parsing-saml-11-ws-federation-tokens.html) shows how to implement WS-Fed *manually* (without any automated way of issuing the request and parsing the token).